# Syncing epub reader

Tags: epub, ebook-readers, nook, android, nook-simple-touch

What epub readers will sync between my Android phone and rooted Nook Simple Touch? (I mean my place in a book, not the books themselves.)

I tried [PageTurner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nightwhistler.pageturner.ads) - and, while it works, it's ugly as sin. Text looks awful, margins are bad.

Ideally I'd use Google Books, but it won't run on my Nook. I tried version 1.6 (I think) and it opens, shows covers, then crashes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Moon+ Reader** can sync between devices, via Dropbox or Google Drive.

It, too, has an ugly UI... but not, I seem to recall, as poor as PageTurner.